# Cloudera Manager Installation failing

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera-manager, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to create a small cluster for testing purposes on EC2 using Cloudera Manager 5.

These are the directions I am following, http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.7.1/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html.

It is getting to the point where it executes, "Execute command SparkUploadJarServiceCommand on service spark" and it fails.

The error is "Upload Spark Jar failed on spark_master".

What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show some logs?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find any additional information.  That is all I am getting.  The only change I have made to those directions is using the CM5 bin file instead of the CM4.

Comment: Apparently it was an open port problem.  I opened up the ones Cloudera listed originally, but just opened up every single one and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the findings as an answer.

You have to open all the required ports for your Cloudera Manager to install it's components correctly.

For a complete guide of ports you need to open refer to:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_ports_cdh4.html

If you are running Cloudera Manager in EC2 you can create a security group that allows all traffic/ports between the Cloudera Manager and its nodes.